# Specify the number of map-slots in concurrent hadoop jobs

Tags: hadoop

I have a a hadoop system running. It has all together 8 map slots in parallel. The DFS block size is 128M.

Now suppose I have two jobs: both of them have large input files, say a hundred G. I want them to run in parallel in the hadoop system. (Because the users do not want to wait. They want to see some progress.) I want the first ones take 5 map slots in parallel, the second one runs on the rest 3 map slots. Is that possible to specify the number of map-slots? Currently I use command line to start it as Hadoop jar jarfile classname input output. Can I specify it in the command line?

Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Resource allocation can be done using a Scheduler. Classic Hadoop uses a [JobQueueTaskScheduler](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml), while YARN uses [CapacityScheduler](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) by default. According to the Hadoop [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html)

> This document describes the CapacityScheduler, a pluggable scheduler for Hadoop which allows for multiple-tenants to securely share a large cluster such that their applications are allocated resources in a timely manner under constraints of allocated capacities.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me check it first